# Типизация аргументов в php

Tags: типизация, php

```
function (classname $arg)
```

Объявленная таким образом функция будет принимать в качестве аргумента только экземпляр типа classname, иначе будет сгенерировано исключение. Но встроенные типы данных не являются классами. 
Отсюда два вопроса:

- где в документации освещается данная фича;
- можно ли ограничить тип аргумента встроенными типами данных непосредственно при объявлении функции.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Нашел таки [документацию](http://ch2.php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.typehinting.php).
2. Ограничить аргумент встроенными типами, за исключением массива, нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

Для примитивных типов - нельзя. И у Вас ошибка (опечатка?) вот в чем: "только экземпляр класса classname". Не только. Правильнее "экземпляр типа classname". Там ведь и имя интерфейса можно передавать.

Comment: Не нашел документации данного поведения, поэтому ошибся. Ткните, пожалуйста, носом.

Comment: В php начиная с 5й версии вполне сносно реализован ООП. Искать сейчас я ничего не буду)) Погуглите про полиморфизм. Уверен, всё найдёте.

Comment: Не совсем понял при чем здесь ООП. Но все равно спасибо)

Comment: А я Вам говорю: почитайте про полиморфизм. Это один из базовых принципов ООП, который реализуется в т.ч. и через передачу типа объекта.

Comment: Базовые принципы ООП я знаю и осознаЮ. Но не понимаю: как полиморфизм связан с ограничением типа аргумента при объявлении функции? Если вы имеете в виду костыль с конвертацией стандартных типов в классы, то вопрос был не об этом.